# Finding the area of a region defined by a polar curve that is outside another polar curve region?

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

I'm stuck with a problem that despite a good bit of searching and even toying around with wolfram|alpha, I can't find an answer to:

**Find the area of the region inside r=5sinθ but outside r=4**

I have seen how to find the area outside of one region but inside another, but I can't find a way to apply those to this problem. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The first step that you need to do is identify the measure of the angles that define the intersection point(s) of your curves. In this case, the intersections of $r=5\sin(\theta)$ and $r=4$. After equating equations and comparing the possible solutions that would make sense graphically, we see that $\theta=\arcsin(\frac{4}{5})$ and $\theta=\pi-\arcsin(\frac{4}{5})$ fit what is required.

Next, we see that the curve $r=5\sin(\theta)$ is above the curve $r=4$, so we will subtract $r=4$ from $r=5\sin(\theta)$ in our integral. This integral will be of the form $\frac{1}{2}\int_\alpha^\beta (5\sin(\theta))^2-4^2 d\theta$. By applying the angles identified above and evaluating, the integral is $$\frac{1}{2}\int_{\arcsin(\frac{4}{5})}^{\pi-\arcsin(\frac{4}{5})} 25\sin^2(\theta)-16\;d\theta=6-\frac{7\pi}{4}+\frac{7}{2}\arcsin\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)\approx3.7477$$